# Not only split a file every N lines, but also specify variable PAGENUMBER header and constant footer for each separated file

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, awk

I've found many code examples of how to split the file into multiple pieces, but – strange enough – I haven't found the solution for this problem.

So, if I have a huge input file:

**input.txt**:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

How to split it every 3 lines, insert pagenumber in the beginning and "The end" message in the end?

**part1.txt**:

```
Page 1
A
B
C
The end
```

**part2.txt**:

```
Page 2
D
E
F
The end
```

**part3.txt**:

```
Page 3
G
H
The end
```

All I've found in the entire Web is this awk code:

```
awk 'END {printf "The end", c > f}
!(NR%3) || NR == 1 {if (f) {printf "The end", c > f; close (f)}
printf "Page %03d\n", ++c > (f = "path/to/part" c ".txt")}
{print > f}' path/to/input.txt
```

but it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    part=1;
    print("Part "part) > "part"part".txt";
}

{
    if (NR%3 == 0 ) {
        print($0) > "part"part".txt";
        print("The end") > "part"part".txt";
        part++;
        print("Part "part) > "part"part".txt";
    } else {
        print($0) > "part"part".txt";
    }
}

END {
    print("The end") > "part"part".txt";
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat part{1..3}.txt
Part 1
A
B
C
The end
Part 2
D
E
F
The end
Part 3
G
H
The end
```

Comment: This is close! But this creates an extra file named "part4.txt" with no content, but with `"Page 4"` header and footer

Comment: I guess you have a blank line are the end of the file, this is causing  `part4.txt` to be created with header and footer. We can omit the blank lines with `getline` statement.

Answer (score 1):

awk way

Bit long atm i'll try and shorten it

```
awk 'NR%3==1{if(x)print "The end" > f;$0="Page "++x"\n"$0;f="part"x".txt"}{print > f}END{print "The end" > f}' file
```

With `close`

```
awk 'NR%3==1{if(x){print "The end" > f;close(f)}$0="Page "++x"\n"$0;f="part"x".txt"}{print > f}END{print "The end" > f}' file
```

#### Output

`Part1.txt`

```
Page 1
A
B
C
The end
```

`Part2.txt`

```
Page 2
D
E
F
The end
```

`Part3.txt`

```
Page 3
G
H
The end
```

Comment: Why am I not seeing `close` in the code? Many code samples that I've seen use this...

Comment: Because you (probably) don't need it ? Unless you are opening a ridiculous amount of files then it doesn't matter. Ill add an edit for you though if you want a `close` file.

Comment: Depends on the platform.  Some places, "ridiculous amont" is actually ridiculously low.

Comment: @tripleee i have never had to use close, but anyway i have added an answer that includes it :)

Comment: @Jidder: Did you test this? I tested this in busybox, got just one file named "part.txt"

Comment: Yes i did test it, i have no idea why you would get that. as far as i can tell this should work with all versions of awk, i will happily accept anyone else's opinion on this though. If i were you i would remove parts to check which part isn't working. For example just use `awk 'NR%3==1{print "Page "++x"\n","part"x".txt"}'` and tell me what that outputs.

Comment: I pasted exactly this in the command line: `awk 'NR%3==1{print "Page "++x"\n","D:/path/part"x".txt"}' D:/path/input.txt`. Its output on the screen is (I use the dots here to indicate newlines): `0 . D:/path/part.txt . 1 . D:/path/part.txt . 2 . D:/path/part.txt`

Comment: Thats really weird,the fact that it has output a 0 even though its using `++x` amongst other things. what does `awk --version` output ?

Comment: @Jidder: `busybox: unknown option -- version > BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-09-26 07:33:17 CEST) multi-call binary. >  Usage: awk [OPTIONS] [AWK_PROGRAM] [FILE]...  >  -v VAR=VAL Set variable >  -F SEP Use SEP as field separator > -f FILE >  Read program from FILE > -e AWK_PROGRAM`

Answer (score 0):

Although you could do this with one awk and redirect output to file by setting filename based on another counter variable kind of but i could think of combination of awk and split like below:

```
awk 'BEGIN {k=1;print "Page 1"} {i++; print $NF;if (i%3 == 0) {print "The end"; k++; printf ("Page %d\n", k)}} END{print "The end"}' /path/to/test.txt | split -l 5 -d - /path/to/part
```

awk - have three part in above

BEGIN - at begining print page1 by default.
Main block - print the entire row and check if we are on third, sixth etc. (i.e. multiple of three) line in a file, print the end and print page number for next.
End - At last print the end for last page
split - will split 5 lines in a file with prefix "Part" and suffix as "01" then "02" which you could change.

Comment: Where is the output filename? What is `5`? Number of lines?

Comment: Yes its number of lines per file. I have updated the answer to say what it means.

Comment: If I'm in the folder `D:/path/folder`, do I need to paste `D:/path/folder/test.txt | split -l 5 - D:/path/folder/part`?

Comment: Yes but what's D: seems windows drive?

Comment: Ok try it and see if that helps you.

Comment: It doesn't work in my busybox: `unknown option -- d BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-09-26 07:33:17 CEST) multi-call binary`

Comment: What if you remove -d from split? -d is for suffix like 00, 01 insteadit will split in as aa, bb etc

Comment: My busybox froze. I closed it. Looked into my folder, saw two files:partaa, partab with no extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You  can simplify your awk script a lot.

I would do something like

```
$ awk 'NR%3==1{count++;} {print > "part"count".txt"}' input
```

which will give an output as

```
part1.txt
A
B
C
part2.txt
D
E
F
part3.txt
G
H
```

Comment: This works, but does not have the header and footer in the files.